# ActiveRecord complains column (for reference) doesn't exist, so I create it manually and it complains it does exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Assuming for the following migration:

```
class AddSectionReferences < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    add_reference :sections, :sections, index: true, foreign_key: true, on_delete: :nullify 
    add_reference :sections, :parent
  end
end
```

It complains:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "section_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "sections" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_810c69e885"
```

so if I add:

```
add_column :sections, :sections_id, :integer
```

before the reference it then complains:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "sections_id" of relation "sections" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "sections" ADD "sections_id" integer
```

What is going on, why is it looking for a `section_id` column in the first error when I'm trying to create a plural column (for a has_many)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I'm trying to create a plural column (for a `has_many`)?

You're approaching this from the wrong end. How do you imagine this column to contain multiple/infinite ids? It's not how rails expects things to be.

In a `has_many` relationship, the foreign key column is on the `belongs_to` side. And column name should be singular, naturally. For it can only hold one id.

```
t.references :section
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association OP should follow this

Comment: @Mark: you think that's the case?

Comment: @Mark: the guide - that's for certain. It's just that your link points directly to `has_many :through` section. And I'm not yet sure about that.

Comment: Ahhh I'm with you yup I linked to the wrong section my bad! But it probably won't hurt him to read it anyway :)